# Doc2Vec Input from Paragraphs

Tags: nlp, gensim

I understand how doc2vec works, but I am unclear the best practice on feeding in data.

Suppose we have a document with multiple sentences

['I really love football. Peyton Manning was a great player']

If we feed this into the algorithm as is, the window for 'Peyton' could include ['love','football','Manning','was']

This doesn't make intuitive sense to me, however, since the words come from different sentences.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be great to understand the down stream application you want to use this. Would help a lot to answer.

Comment: @gojomo answers a somewhat related question. You might find his comments helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014463/hierarchical-training-for-doc2vec-how-would-assigning-same-labels-to-sentences

Answer (score 1):

The aim of Doc2Vec is to produce document level embeddings, thus even if words are sentence-separated if you include them in the same document it has to be considered part of the same semantic source for word similarities. If you don't want such a behavior, you might want to separate your documents in a sentence-level and maybe aggregate the embeddings later in different groups to form your initial paragraphs (depending on your plans)?

Answer (score 0):

With Doc2Vec, each string will be treated as a separate document regardless of any formatting such as sentences or paragraphs. So for an analysis of a book from project Gutenberg, you could have each chapter of the book treated as a document or you could treat each paragraph as a document.

So, for a two sentence paragraph like your example  ['I really love football. Peyton Manning was a great player'] and use a sentence tokenizer such as the NLTK package in Python's nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenizer() function which will divide your string into separate sentences.  You would then run the tokenized sentences through Doc2Vec and have each sentence as a different document.  See [this example](http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-ii-sentence-tokenize-and-word-tokenize) for an example with a sentence tokenizer in Python

The choice of which level of text to treat as a document should be based on what your research design is and what unit of analysis you want to interpret for the end product.  You tagged the question with gensim, so I assume you are trying to do a topic model. You have to weigh whether you are interested on change in topics from sentence to sentence, in paragraph chunks, or some other hierarchy within the text.